# Where can I find information on a WWI soldier?

Tags: 20th-century, war, world-war-one, 1910s

Does anyone know where to find details on WWI soldiers? I am researching a captain called Thomas Zachary Woods. Thus far I have found this website: http://doingourbit.ca/profile/thomas-woods. Where can I find out more about this soldier?

Comment: What information is available, other than name and rank? Country? Unit? Year(s) of service? General location of service? Wounded? Killed? Missing in action? Punching the name into Google gives me this on the first page of results: "Born in Canada on 2 JUN 1862 to Frederick Stevenson Woods and Jane Baily. Thomas Zachary Woods passed away on 9 Apr 1916 in Flanders - WW1." Is that possibly the person you are researching?

Comment: Also on first page of Google results is [this](https://www.veterans.gc.ca/eng/remembrance/memorials/canadian-virtual-war-memorial/detail/433037): "Captain Thomas Zachary Woods. April 9, 1916. Age: 52. Force: Army. Unit: Canadian Infantry Brigade. Cemetery: LIJSSENTHOEK MILITARY CEMETERY Belgium. Grave Reference: V. A. 17. Son of Frederick S. Woods and Jane (his wife). Born near Brantford, Ontario. Served in the North-West Canada (Riel's Rebellion 1885) and the South African Campaigns."

Comment: The Lijssenhoek Cemetery has additional [information](http://www.lijssenthoek.be/en/adres/3370/-thomas-zachary-woods.html): "two brothers, Francis and Alfred; Profession: Veterinary surgeon; Medals: Queen's Medal, four clasps; Regiment and unit: Canadian Army Veterinary Corps attd. 2nd Bde.HQ / 1st Can.Div.; Wounded: 6 April, Poperinge. Died of shell wounds, left arm and compound fracture left femur, amputated, in n°10 CCS"

Comment: The Lijssenhoek Cemetery also provides a scan of his record in the graves registry, stating next of kin as "F. B. Woods, Gilbert Plains, Man., Canada."

Comment: There's a genealogy.SE site (https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/). They'd be much much better than us at knowing how to track down info from public records about non-famous individuals.

Comment: Some reasons why your questions is being poorly received (as evidenced by the downvote): (1) Reference questions, such as "*Where can I find info on TZW?*", are off-topic for the site. Phrase instead as: "*I've found the following details for TZW: ... from this web site. Can anyone help me find out more? I've also checked ABC and DEFF without any success.*"

Comment: Some other tips that might be helpful: (1) Questions should be self-contained, if possible. Provide known information in the question, use links to back it up with references (reason: links can and will rot away). (2) It should be clear from the question that straightforward Google searches have already been tried (reason: many potential answerers would prefer not to be in a "Let me Google that for you" role).

Answer (score 3):

The service file for Captain Thomas Zachary Woods at [Library & Archives Canada](https://www.bac-lac.gc.ca/eng/discover/military-heritage/first-world-war/personnel-records/Pages/item.aspx?IdNumber=321879).

His burial information with the [Commonwealth War Graves Commission](https://www.cwgc.org/find-records/find-war-dead/casualty-details/433037/thomas-zachary-woods/).

And the [Canadian Virtual War Memorial](https://www.veterans.gc.ca/eng/remembrance/memorials/canadian-virtual-war-memorial/detail/433037?Thomas%20Zachary%20Woods).

Comment: Don't forget [Wikitree](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Woods-11130): "6 April 1916, Poperinge, Wounded in shelling, while he was inspecting horse lines as VO to the 2nd CIB.
9 April 1916 Died of shell wounds, left arm and compound fracture left femur, amputated, in n°10 CCS."